# How do I get total number of objects in a variable only once?

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I am new to JS so struggling with this a bit.

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some_url",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (whatever) {
                var allText = whatever.data._shared.text;
                for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
                    var text1 = allText[i];
                    var testHtml = "";
                    testHtml += "";
                    testHtml += "";
                    testHtml += "";
                    $("#text").append(testHtml);
                    document.write(allText.length);
                }

            }

        });

    });
```

In a variable I want the total count of objects returned (allText = whatever.data._shared.text).

I tested out by using document.write(allText.length); and I am getting the right number but the result looks like this:

2020202020202020202020202020202020202020

So it appears to be repeating.  How can I get the actual value, which is 20, inside a variable only once instead of it repeating?

Comment: Print it outside the `for` loop. It doesn't depend on anything in the loop.

Comment: What's the point of all those `testHtml += "";` lines? Why are you appending empty strings to an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `document.write(allText.length);` *inside* the for loop, so one time per iteration (so you write it 20 times). Try to call it *outside* the for loop:

```
var allText = whatever.data._shared.text;
for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
    var text1 = allText[i];
    var testHtml = "";
    testHtml += "";
    testHtml += "";
    testHtml += "";
    $("#text").append(testHtml);
}
document.write(allText.length);
```

Also try to use your browser's debugger (go step by step) to understand what happened.